# How do I write string array data to an output file in c++

Tags: c++, arrays

So recently I have been developing a program that asks the user some questions and asks for their reply, it then stores it to an array, and writes it out to an output file, although I don't get the information the user inputs but this code thing: `0x4080c0`. Can someone please help me, here is my code as well:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string q1 = "Distance Flown:";
string q2 = "Total Fuel Used:";
string q3 = "Total Flight Time:";
string q4 = "Number Of Passengers:";
string q5 = "Total Profit:";
string q6 = "Any futher comments goes here:";

string logAwensers[6];

int main()
{
cout << "Please enter your pilot log here."<< endl;
cout << q1 << endl;
getline(cin, logAwensers[0]);
cout << q2 << endl;
getline(cin, logAwensers[1]);
cout << q3 << endl;
getline(cin, logAwensers[2]);
cout << q4 << endl;
getline(cin, logAwensers[3]);
cout << q5 << endl;
getline(cin, logAwensers[4]);
cout << q6 << endl;
getline(cin, logAwensers[5]);

cout << logAwensers << endl;
ofstream writer("PilotLog.txt", ios::app);

if(! writer)
{
    cout << "Error writing file" << endl;
}

    return -1;
}
writer << logAwensers << endl;
writer.close();
return 0;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You should indent your code properly. The `}` after `return -1;` is closing main function. And please, don't use global variables.

Comment: Oh okay sorry, I forgot to mention i'm new to programming.

Comment: And, you are currently writting the address of the array. Use a for loop, or write each element one by one. (No need to mention, it's obvious ;))

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but probably good fundamental business to learn/gain awareness of: [Why is “using namespace std” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/6610379)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of:

```
cout << logAwensers << endl;
```

Try something like:

```
for (const auto &a : logAwensers)
{
    cout << a << endl;
}
```

Comment: No copy needed here -> `auto const &`.

Comment: I'll leave that one to the compiler.

Comment: Leave what? `auto` deduction doesn't keep `const` and `&` qualifiers.

Comment: I don't see what would stop the compiler from taking care of that.  The code is fairly simple.

Anyway, I'll modify it just to make it easier for you to go to sleep tonight.

Comment: Because you're asking it not to. That's simple.

Comment: I disagree.  The compiler can do whatever it wants to do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162861/discussion-between-sid-s-and-oneil).

Comment: Thanks you very much.